# Cannot acquire serial port names in WinForms

Tags: c#

I am intend to design a GUI for my arduino project. However, I couldn’t get serial port names. I inserted the necessary library, and used `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` method. Then, I tried to add port names into `ComboBox`, also tried `ListBox` later, via `foreach` function. Eventually, I couldn’t see any port name neither in the program nor in the `Item->(Collectibles)`. However, I used a button which shows port names in `MessageBox`, and I saw only `COM3` and `COM4`.
I am sorry if I am confusing, thank you for yourr further comments.

Comment: `The necessary library` which library? [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8) is a .NET class. Besides serial ports don't have names. Their only names are `COM1`, `COM2` etc. What you see in Device Manager is a description added by the driver itself.

Comment: `string[] names = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();`? Which are read from *registry* `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`

Comment: As the method's [doc page explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames?view=netframework-4.8) `The port names are obtained from the system registry (for example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM). If the registry contains stale or otherwise incorrect data then the GetPortNames method will return incorrect data.`

Comment: Given that modern PCs *don't* have serial ports, you're probably trying to use a serial device over a virtual serial port. Whether it's a USB dongle or Serial over Ethernet, it's still a virtual serial port and requires a driver at least. Serial over Ethernet *doesn't* support Plug&Play - your computer can't know that a POS appeared somewhere on the network. You may have to configure your device or run its configuration program to make it appear as a serial port on Windows

Comment: I can select the proper port by using TextBox, but it is just a bit tiring to look up Arduino Interface, find the port name, and enter the port name to TextBox manually.

Comment: @Zusaetlich so there's no serial port at all, there's a USB connection to Arduino and an *emulated* port without a name. Even the Arduino IDE shows `COM3` and `COM4`